# How to move to next or previous step in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using ui-route for routing. There are multiple sequential form.
When I submit a form after that I want to got to next step form(step).
I don't want to hard code step name in $state.go() function. 
Is there a way to get next and previous state?

```
  $stateProvider
               .state("Cars", {
                  url: "/",
                  templateUrl: "/rc1/renderStep/cars",
               })
               .state("Drivers", {
                  url: "/drivers",
                  templateUrl: "/rc1/renderStep/drivers",
                  controller: "renderStepCtrl",
               })
        }])
```

state change call

```
$scope.onSubmit = function () {
                  postDtoFactory.postDto(); 
                  console.info('current page= '+$state.current.name);
                  //console.log('prev = '+$state.previous.route.name);
                  $state.go();
               };
```

Comment: $state.current.name ++; ??? Not sure what you want

If it's not a number do you have a mapping of the "next state" We're missing a whole lot of context here

Comment: $state.current.name gives current state name, when I call $state.go() this shold redirect to Drivers state. . this is next state if I am  in Cars page.

Comment: Do you have a mapping of that or something? Or could you make a function which determines what the next state should be? If so you could just call that function on the current scope or w/e.

This sounds like logic you can't magically get to work but requires some manual coding.

Comment: $state don''t have function like next() or previous() instead of writing mapping or params with state.

Answer (score 1):

> Save previous state manually,by creationg a listener

```
 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, to, toParams, from, fromParams) {
        //save the previous state in a rootScope variable so that it's accessible from everywhere
        $rootScope.previousState = from;
    });
  }]);
$scope.onSubmit = function(){
  //if u want to go on previous state
  $state.go($rootScope.previousState.name)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thatkookooguy :)

Comment: Thanks, and how to get next step.  $state.go($rootScope.nextState.name), will it work?

Comment: You can simply right $state.go("the state on which u want to go").Isn't it?If not ,please clarify what u mean.